# Some methods contain a Compiled Code?

Tags: java

From going to the source of some classes I saw some methods contain a compiled code, they are looks like this before expanding:

`public void someMethod(){`
 <kbd>Compiled Code</kbd> 
`}`

When expanding the method you can see the codes inside it are written as a comment.

See one of the method from `sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder`:

```
    public boolean isFileSystem() {
     // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Compiled Code">
     /* 0: aload_0
     * 1: invokevirtual #362  // Method getPath:()Ljava/lang/String;
     * 4: ldc           #7    // String ShellFolder
     * 6: invokevirtual #342  // Method java/lang/String.startsWith:(Ljava/lang/String;)
      /........
   */
      // </editor-fold>
    }
```

I am interested to know more about those methods and what language is used.
Is it possible to write my own compiled code?

Comment: That is Java. That's JVM bytecode (the `.class` file) reverse-engineered. They show that when they don't have access to the actual source code.

Comment: As an exercise, look for the tool called `javap` (it comes with the JDK, like `javac`). Do this: compile a simple class, say `Test.java`, get to the folder where the compiled `Test.class` is and do `javap -c Test.class`. You'll see exactly that `0: aload_0 1: invokevirtual #362` stuff.

Comment: Note that if the code is not obfuscated, you can decompile with with something like [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr)

Comment: @acdcjunior Is it actually reverse-engineered or is this metadata stored inside the classfile itself?

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee: I am using JD, but this codes are stored in `.java` file and could not be converted to the java code again (I think).

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ The technical term is "disassemble" ([see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html)). I believe the `aload_0`/`invokevirtual` are the actual instructions of the class file (printed as "pretty" strings, in the actual bytecode they are probably integers codes, each code representing a different instruction), but some info is definitely metadata, like line numbers, debugging info ([see -g option here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)) and so.

Comment: @acdcjunior: If you posted the exercise as an answer, I would give you an upvote :) thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is Java(or another JVM-compatible language, as per comment) as well.

When you are given a jar file (such as rt.jar with the JDK/JRE), it is already compiled. High-level code such as:

```
HashMap<Foo, Bar> baz=Quuz.getInstance(); //This is obviously fake
```

is turned into low-level bytecode that is not human-readable.

This bytecode contains metadata such as method argument types, and information needed for loading these classes and methods. It is needed for IDEs to offer syntax completion for libraries(such as jars you add to project classpaths) and more importantly for loading and using methods of the classes you get from these libraries.

The "code" you see here is a summary, and a type of code called bytecode. Line by line, instructions like `ldc` seen in your example operate on small portions of a stack that powers the JVM at a time. This bytecode is fairly difficult to read and program in by hand, so your compiler will generate it for you.

All of this (except for some native methods) is implemented in a JVM-compatible language.

Depending on the library and its restrictions, as well as your IDE's functionality, it may be possible to get the full source code in another package and "attach" it so your IDE shows the source instead of the machine-generated summary, or to decompile it back to Java source code with the same functionality<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> The Java compiler generally outputs bytecode that is fairly easy to convert back to source code with the same function (not true of other compiled languages such as C/C++). It is possible to obfuscate code using a tool such as Proguard, which replaces identifiers with nonsense ones, and can additionally convert certain operations to highly unclear ones with the same result when executed.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be java. Could be any compiled JVM language.

Comment: @Ingo Sorry about that, I don't have much experience outside of java itself.

Comment: No issue. Most of the time it *will* be java anyway. Added this just for completeness.

Comment: @Ingo Out of curiosity, can the language used be determined from the compiled class-file? Is it somewhere in the metadata?

Comment: I think you can pretty well, by just checking for certain patterns, like naming conventions, annotations, etc. For example, the JVM language Frege compiles to classes that have Annotations of type frege.runtime.Meta

Answer (score 2):

Compiled code just means that the IDE doesn't have the source available to it (but the code is written in Java). The `sun.*` classes typically don't make their source available because they have a non-public API. This shouldn't be confused with `native` code, which can be written in C/C++ and called through JNI/JNA.